# Cannot fetch data using swift from a local vapor service

Tags: swift, vapor

I am coding a local vapor service and giving it a route, the server starts and prints `Server starting on http://localhost:8080`

There is the route like follow:

```swift
router.get("cupcakes") { req -> Future<[Cupcake]> in
    return Cupcake.query(on: req).all()
}
```

Then I code a request in `SwiftUI` app and decode the call-back, as follows:

```swift
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
print("222")
if let decoded = try? decoder.decode([Cupcake].self, from: data) {
    print("666")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.cupcakes = decoded
        print("5555")
    }
} else {
    print("789")
}
```

In console it prints `22`, then `666`, then `789`.

Comment: I think it would be better to first of all try to decode it in `do/catch` to see the error

Comment: Also if you just started with Vapor then choose version 4, cause version 3 is obsolete

Comment: btw join official vapor chat in discord to be in touch with our pleasant community

Comment: there is nothing about SwiftUI here